# Exponential regression fit overestimates

Tags: regression, nonlinear-regression, exponential-distribution

I have a non-linear data set that I used to fit an hyperbolic curve of the following format:

$$ q = \frac{q_i}{(1+bD_it)^{1/b}}$$

$t$ is the x-axis (independent variable), $q$ is the y-axis (dependent variable), and $q_i, b, D_i$ are parameters that I fit. I fitted my data using the below code snippet. Note that running the following code will generate the exact looking plot below. You can directly access the same data set I used.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

##################################### Prepare Data #########################################

file = 'https://aegis4048.github.io/downloads/notebooks/sample_data/decline_curve.xlsx'
df = pd.read_excel(file, sheet_name='sheet_1')
df = df[df['Oil Prod. (bopd)'] > 200]           # remove bad data points
t = df['Time'][1:].values
y = df['Oil Prod. (bopd)'][1:].values
x = np.array([i for i in range(len(t))])

#################################### Define function #######################################

def hyperbolic(x, qi, b, Di):
    return qi / (1 + b * Di * x) ** (1 / b)

####################################### Curve Fit ##########################################

popt, pcov = curve_fit(hyperbolic, x, y, maxfev=10000, p0=[max(y), 0.1, 0.1])

fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(14, 4))
axes[0].plot(x, y, '--o', color='k', alpha=1)
axes[0].plot(x, hyperbolic(x, *popt), color='r', label='P50')

axes[1].plot(x, y, '--o', color='k', alpha=1)
axes[1].plot(x, hyperbolic(x, *popt), color='r', label='P50')
axes[1].set_yscale('log')
```

[image]

The resulting regression model overestimates the right tail of the data. I suspect this is because the magnitude of the data is much bigger on the left side, and that the regression fit is putting more emphasis on the left side than the right side. As such, when plotted on linear scale, the it seems to be a good fit, but when plotted on an log scale, you can clearly see the overestimation.

**Question 1**: How can I improve the quality of the fit for the portions with smaller magnitude, other than manually changing parameters?

**Question 2**: I thought about doing log-transformation and then fitting, but my professor told me that doing so may introduce bias during the forward & back transformation processes, and that I should be careful about that. Why would that be?

Comment: Those outliers around $x=35$ are going to pull your estimated curve up; you should probably either remove them or use a robust estimation routine instead of `curve_fit`.

Comment: @jbowman I tried manually removing them and it worked... omg. I can't believe that I didn't think about it

Comment: That the local variation apparent in these log-linear plots appears to have around the same magnitude across the range of explanatory values indicates you *should* be fitting the logarithm of the response. Your model is inappropriate in that (1) it does not accommodate the outliers and (2) it assumes the local variation is constant on a *linear* scale, which is grossly incorrect. As suggested by @jbowman, fix the first problem by using a robust estimator and fix the second one by using log(q) rather than q as the response. BTW, in what sense are these "hyperparameters" and not just parameters?

Comment: @whuber I fixed the hyperparameters -> parameters. I don't understand "(2) it assumes the local variation is constant on a linear scale, which is grossly incorrect". Can you explain more about this? I also don't understand how using log(q) helps, as the non-linear regression model should be able to fit the data well, when there's no outliers? I tried removing the outlier points in the middle as "jbowman" suggested, and obtained a really good curve

Comment: My experience has often been that when the curve is good enough - or as you say, *really* good - you are done with the modeling part of the work.

Comment: See our posts that discuss the concept and analysis of regression residuals.